# List out of bounds 0 exception

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity-lineitem, opp-lineitemschedule

I am trying to change the Opportunity Line Item schedule when a custom field is changed. The schedule works fine when the field is enterd, but when I edit the custom field it throws the exception. I did try null check for the list but that is messing up the schedule. Greatly appreciate any help on this

Here is the trigger and the class

Trigger

```
trigger OpportunityReScheduling on Opportunity (after update, before update, after insert) 
    {
        for (Opportunity o: Trigger.new)
        {
            if (Trigger.isBefore)
            {
                if(o.Category__c == 'Solutions'){
                Opportunity prevOpportunity = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.ID);
                    if(o.Effective_Date__c <> null){
                if (o.Effective_Date__c != prevOpportunity.Effective_Date__c) 
                {
                    Integer DayDiff = prevOpportunity.Effective_Date__c.daysBetween(o.Effective_Date__c);

                    OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleDateUpdate(o.id, DayDiff);
                }
            }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

CLass

```
public with sharing class OpportunitySchedulingHandler {

     //Update LineItemSchedule dates for all scheduling dates

    public static void ScheduleDateUpdate(String oppid, Integer DayDiff)

    {

       List<OpportunityLineItem> idval = [SELECT id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId=:oppid];

       List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> datelist = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();

       for (Integer i = 0; i < idval.size(); i++)

       {

           datelist = [SELECT ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId =:idval[i].id];

           Date firstDate = datelist[0].ScheduleDate.addDays(DayDiff);

           datelist[0].ScheduleDate = firstDate;

           Integer day = firstDate.day();

           Integer month = firstDate.month();

           Integer year = firstDate.year();

           for (Integer k = 1; k < datelist.size(); k++)

           {

               Integer nYear = year;

               Integer nMonth = month + k;

               Integer nDay = day;

               if (nMonth > 12) {
                nMonth = nMonth - 12;

                   nYear = nYear + 1;

               }

               Set<Integer> longMonths = new Set<Integer> {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};


               if (nDay == 31 && ! longMonths.contains(nMonth)) {

                   nDay = 30;

               }

               if (nDay > 28 && nMonth == 2) {

                   nDay = 28;

               }

               Date mydate = date.newInstance(nYear,nMonth,nDay);

               datelist[k].ScheduleDate = mydate;

           }

           if(!datelist.isEmpty())

           {

                update datelist;

           }

        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Please dont write "soql"query inside for loop!!!!...

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a query like this one:

```
       datelist = [SELECT ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId =:idval[i].id];
```

You don't need to be checking for `datelist` to be `null`. It won't be. If something goes wrong with the query, you'll simply get an exception.

Instead, you need to check for `datelist.size() > 0` prior to referencing `datelist[0]`. You are attempting to access an element that is beyond the bounds of the list, the bounds being empty (no items at all).

Your code has a much deeper issue, however. You are performing a SOQL query inside not one but two `for` loops. You call `OpportunitySchedulingHandler.ScheduleDateUpdate` once per Opportunity, and then within that method you perform SOQL once for the `OpportunityLineItem` list and then once per `OpportunityLineItem` to obtain `OpportunityLineItemSchedule`. You're going to need to put some work into [bulkifying](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_bulk) this trigger before you take it to production.

Comment: I did try that initially , but I think I had two conditions where I was looking if the list is null and the size, and that messed up.  Now I am able to fix the issue. Somehow I am still unable to create the schedule directly off the custom field instead of Opportunity Close Date. Is that the standard way?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what that means - I don't really work with line item schedules. If this issue is solved, please consider accepting an answer and opening a new question for any separate issues.

Comment: That said, I'd really recommend refactoring and bulkifying the code *before* trying to debug, as you have some radical changes to make.